# Keras incremental categorical training

Tags: keras

If I have simple network like the following:

```
mod = Sequential()
mod.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', name='input', input_dim=input_size))
mod.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', name='hidden'))
mod.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='output'))
```

that outputs a 5 category class.
If I train each class separately in order words I repeat the following process:

step #1

```
mod.fit(...) # training file contains data of only class 1
mod.save()
```

step #2

```
mod.load()
mod.fit(...) # training file contains data of only class 2
mod.save()
```

I observed that although the weights are carried over from the first fit/save when I try to predict using class 1 and 2 samples it only predicts class 2. (looks like ignoring the first data fit of class 1).
Finally if I join the training data of class 1 and 2 into a single file and I train this file then the prediction results are accurate.
Does this means that for such a simple network can not perform incremental training as described. If not any ideas as to do incremental training as suggested?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this incremental training? That is not how a multi-class NN is typicall trained.

Comment: Matias thanks for the reply. What exactly is the purpose of this incremental training? This is because it is not possible to collect all the training data at once.  Also let's assume that I initially use a training file that includes samples of every class and I trained my network and hence my predictions are accurate. If I wish to repeat the training process with a single class training file would my previous "good" training data be overwritten with the current training data? Any way to avoid such scenario

Comment: You cannot train with a single class, that simply is not going to work at all. Using mini-batches should be the solution when you can't load the whole dataset at once, but that includes all classes.

Answer (score 0):

one class traing cant learn anything  because there is no  alternatieves

so
train file that includes samples of every class save it

if you want to repeat the training process with a single class training file

add some old data with other class data items to equilize class distribition

then load saved network

with this small data set, apply transfer learning  ( learn only classifier layer )